# Color Scheme Switcher - Pure JS

Tags: color

помогите мне с кодом ниже, как сделать, чтобы после перезапуска страницы цвет остался прежним?

```js
document.getElementById('grayButton').onclick = switchGray;
document.getElementById('whiteButton').onclick = switchWhite;
document.getElementById('blueButton').onclick = switchBlue;
document.getElementById('yellowButton').onclick = switchYellow;

function switchGray() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'gray'; 
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'white'; 
}

function switchWhite() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white'; 
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'black'; 
}

function switchBlue() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; 
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'white'; 
}

function switchYellow() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; 
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'black'; 
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


#switcher {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#switcher li {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#grayButton {
  background: gray;
}
#whiteButton {
  background: white;
}
#blueButton {
  background: blue;
}
#yellowButton {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul id="switcher">
  <li id="grayButton"></li>
  <li id="whiteButton"></li>
  <li id="blueButton"></li>
  <li id="yellowButton"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прикладываю код решения задачи, в песочнице SO он работать не будет.

Но будет работать на [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/70Lptn54/1/).

Немного объясню логику скрипта.

1. В начале мы задаем объект, содержащий все наши темы.
2. Затем мы выбираем элемент к которому будем цеплять наш класс, по умолчанию это `body`
3. После этого мы возьмем значение темы из локального хранилища и установим его в качестве темы по умолчанию
4. Если тема в локальном хранилище будет недоступна/удалена/не задана, то по умолчанию сработает тема `gray`.
5. Теперь применяем нашу тему на указанном элементе
6. Выбираем все элементы содержащие атрибут `data-theme` и вешаем на них событие `click`
7. В обработчике `switchThemeHandle` мы проверяем наличие темы из заданного объекта
8. Сбрасываем все темы что были установлены до этого с помощью `regex`'a
9. Устанавливаем указанную тему и сохраняем значение в `localStorage`

```js
// Объект содержащий все темы
const themes = {
    gray: 'theme--gray',
    red: 'theme--red',
    green: 'theme--green',
    blue: 'theme--blue'
}

// Выбираем элемент у которого будет изменяться класс.
const themeElement = document.body;

// Берем название темы из локального хранилища
const themeFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('theme');

// Создаем тему по умолчанию, если тема не найдена, сработает условие.
const defaultTheme = themes[themeFromStorage] || themes.gray;

// Устанавливаем тему по умолчанию.
themeElement.classList.add(defaultTheme);

// Выбираем все элементы у которых есть аттрибут data-theme.
const themeSwitchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-theme]');

// Перебираем все элементы и вешаем на них событие отслеживающее нажатие.
for (const switcher of themeSwitchers)
    switcher.addEventListener('click', switchThemeHandle);

// Обработчик смены тем
function switchThemeHandle(e) {
    
    // Получаем значение дата аттрибута
    const { theme } = e.target.dataset;
    
    // Проверяем, есть ли в заданном массиве тем, наша новая тема
    if (!Object.keys(themes).includes(theme)) {
        console.error('Ошибка смены темы. Тема не найдена.');
        return;
    }
    
    // Удаляем все старые темы по условию
    themeElement.className = themeElement.className.replace(/([theme\-\-]+[a-z]+)/, '');
    
    // Добавляем новую тему
    themeElement.classList.add(themes[theme]);
    
    // Сохраняем тему в локальное хранилище
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
}
```

```css
.themes {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
}

.themes > * {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.themes button {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.themes .gray { background-color: #95a5a6; border-color: #7f8c8d; }
.themes .red { background-color: #e74c3c; border-color: #c0392b; }
.themes .green { background-color: #2ecc71; border-color: #27ae60; }
.themes .blue { background-color: #3498db; border-color: #2980b9; }
.themes .unknown { background-color: #9b59b6; border-color: #8e44ad; }

body.theme--gray { background-color: #95a5a6; }
body.theme--red { background-color: #e74c3c; }
body.theme--green { background-color: #2ecc71; }
body.theme--blue { background-color: #3498db; }
```

```html
<div class="themes">
    <button class="gray" data-theme="gray">GRAY</button>
    <button class="red" data-theme="red">RED</button>
    <button class="green" data-theme="green">GREEN</button>
    <button class="blue" data-theme="blue">BLUE</button>
    <button class="unknown" data-theme="unknown">unknown</button>
</div>
```

Comment: как добавить класс или личный идентификатор, например: .names / # names . Я пробовал вот так: const themeElement = document.names; Но так не работает.

Comment: @COOLPIX не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, что именно вы хотите сделать? `themeElement` это элемент, к которому будут добавлены классы, вы хотите заменить его? Если вы хотите добавить новую тему, вам всего-лишь нужно расширить объект `themes`, добавив в него название темы и значение (класс).

Comment: по мимо этого const themeElement = document.body; добавить другие классы

Comment: @COOLPIX вы хотите к другому элементу привязаться и добавлять/удалять классы тем?

Comment: да именно так...

Comment: @COOLPIX `document.querySelector('#myid');` или `document.querySelector('.myclass');`

Comment: добавил вот так: document.querySelector('#opops');   #opops.theme--gray { background-color: #95a5a6; }
#opops.theme--red { background-color: #e74c3c; }
#opops.theme--green { background-color: #2ecc71; }
#opops.theme--blue { background-color: #3498db; } не работает.

Comment: @COOLPIX разместите ваш код на jsfiddle чтобы он был воспроизводимым и я посмотрю

Comment: Здравствуйте
вы не забыл посмотреть мой код, заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/localhost2020/7r9k304c/23/

Comment: @COOLPIX это https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/z9osjy2a/ ?

Comment: да так работает, но я добавил еще один ID, и не работает. возможно добавить  Multiple IDs? Спасибо!

Comment: @COOLPIX https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/tdchrsx1/ . Мне почему-то кажется что вы неправильно меня поняли, когда я давал вам подробный ответ. Вы не должны привязывать классы к каким-то определенным элементам, вы можете от `body` наследовать класс и изменять тот или иной блок в зависимости от этого. Например, `body.theme--red #opops .myclass` и т.д. Вам не нужно вешать на каждый элемент слушатель и изменять классы.

Comment: я решил проблему, спасибо

Comment: у меня еще вопрос возможно как-то сделать чтобы работало с кодом **:after** и **:before**

Comment: тое-сть к примеру есть такой код  <div id='effectlayerinner'></div>

Comment: и вся работа этого кода работает на этом коде: #effectlayerinner:after {
  content: "";
    background-color: #12151c;
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

Comment: #effectlayerinner:before {
  content: "";
    background-color: #000;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

Comment: возможно чтобы этот код читал как-то так: document.getElementById('effectlayerinner:after'); ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116601/discussion-on-answer-by-molof-color-scheme-switcher-pure-js).

Comment: @Barmaley , спасибо

Comment: как сделать чтобы можно добавлять и document.getElementByClassName к этому коду, чтобы было document.gerElementById и ByClassName  ( jsfiddle.net/MoloF/tdchrsx1)